TurtleBot3 tutorial (SLAM) - Camera data is not published (/camera_info)
I am following the Turtlebot3 tutorial about SLAM at the following link. https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/slam/
(Symptom)
I could run the SLAM node, but in RVIZ, there is a warning message "No camera info received on [/camera_info].
(What I've tried)

To manually set the topic name for camera data in RVIZ (as soon as I tried this, RVIZ was terminated)

sudo apt update & apt upgrade (not effective)


How can I receive camera data and see the image through RVIZ?
Any comment will be helpful to me. Thanks.

Initially I would try running:
ros2 topic echo /camera_info
On the robot itself and see is there is any data being published at all.
Also worth checking the logs to see if a node has died/didn't start
